# Why SQL Server does not apply Key Lookup after SELECT TOP?

Tags: sql-server

I have one simple query that selects from 1 table, no join. All columns used for filter or sort have been indexed.

This is what the execution plan looks like:

```
+--------+     +-----+     +--------------+     +------------+
| SELECT | <== | Top | <== | Nested Loops | <== | Index Seek |
+--------+     +-----+     +--------------+ |   +------------+
                                            |
                                            |   +------------+
                                            |__ | Key Lookup |
                                                +------------+
```

SQL only reads the necessary rows when performs `Index Seek`, then follows with a `Key Lookup` for the missing columns (in the `SELECT`), sort everything, then select the top rows.

This is fine, except that if I have to select the last 10 rows and my data have like 80,000 rows in total, SQL will then do a `Key Lookup` on all 80k rows before return the last 10, which doesn't sound right.

I've tried with a dataset contains 11,000 rows. The `Number of Rows Read` is indeed 11,000. Although compare 2 plans (big vs small OFFSET), I don't see many differences in performance (same I/O and CPU cost). But in a production server where the number of rows may be much higher and the query is executed more frequently, will performance become a problem then?

[image: Execution plan of 11k vs 1k rows]

Should I write the query myself to apply `Key Lookup` after `SELECT TOP`: firstly select the necessary row IDs only, then select all columns of those rows?

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch

Comment: Table schema and script wud hv been nice.`Should I write the query myself to apply Key Lookup after SELECT TOP: firstly select the necessary row IDs only, then select all columns of those rows?` --YES why don't you give a try.

Comment: Yes, I tried, it's better. But because I'm using Entity Framework, it's more complicated to do so.

Comment: You can always choose between complex code that performs well and easy code that, well, doesn't